# How to implement customReducer in React-Admin

Tags: redux, react-redux, react-admin

I try to implement a customReducer to manage my own custom state in React-Admin. I have looked through the documentation. I can see where to register the reducer in the `<Admin>`, but I don't see where to really **dispatch** the reducer to store the state.

I also wish to know how to **retrieve** my state from the Redux store. What dataProvider is appropriate for this?

Please could someone share a code snippet to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First - reducers are not dispatched - probably you have meant actions.

After adding the `customReducer` you interact with the store in the usual way any redux store is accessed: throught hooks if functional component `useSelector()` `useDispatch()` or through the `connect` HOC in a class component.

Comment: Thanks Kia as usual. This is answerd